# Custom R Source package in Docker

Tags: r, docker, ubuntu-18.04

InfrastructureR_0.1.4.tar.gz is a R source package that I created using RStudio in windows and it works fine.
But when I try to use it in docker file with the command
InfrastructureR_0.1.4.tar.gz is located in the same location as Docker file

Docker is running on ubuntu 18.x machine

`RUN R -e "install.packages('InfrastructureR_0.1.4.tar.gz', dependencies=FALSE, verbose=TRUE, repos=NULL, type='source')"`
it doesn't install.

I run the docker build by `sudo docker build  -t myRApp s .`
and I get the following error message

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
system (cmd0): /usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL
Warning: invalid package ‘InfrastructureR_0.1.4.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning message:
In install.packages("InfrastructureR_0.1.4.tar.gz", dependencies = FALSE,  :
  installation of package ‘InfrastructureR_0.1.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

So how do I install a custom R source package in Docker

Comment: At a first approximation this has nothing to do with Docker. Did you try installing the package from source on a Linux system? Maybe inside a virtual image? What happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to have your tar.gz file in the same directory as your Dockerfile. To make a local file available to a Docker container created from an image, you can use the `COPY` instruction.

The `COPY` instruction copies new files or directories from `<src>` and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path `<dest>`:

```
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
```

More in the docker docs:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Answer (score 1):

I think the package needs to be copied inside the container so that the container can access it. (or in a location volume that docker has access to)

R running inside the container cannot find the file.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/